# A property about positive definite matrices

Tags: matrices

For any positive definite $n\times n$ matrix $(K)_{ij}$,where $0<i,j<1+n$, we can take a smaller $m \times m$  sub-matrix from the left up corner,$(K)_{a b}$ with $0<a<1+m,0<b<1+m$. Similarly, we can take a $m\times  m$ sub-matrix from the inverse matrix of K,$(K^{-1})_{ab}$.
For these two sub-matices, the claim is that:
for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $(K)_{a b}(K^{-1})_{bc}$, $\lambda\geq1$.

Can someone help me prove it?

Comment: By $(K^{−1})_{bc} $ you mean $(K^{−1})_{ab} $?

Comment: Yes, you first calculate the inverse and then take a sub-matrix from it.

Comment: But you mean the same "position" and dimension submatrix or another casual submatrix of $K^{-1}$?

Comment: I guess it is the same, looking at the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very interesting.

I have a partial answer.

I have written at first a Matlab program (see below) that has shown me different things, in particular that, in many cases, the eigenvalues are 1.

Then, I have tried to understand with the help of block decomposition; I will take in the following the particular case where n=4, i.e., $K \in \mathbb{R}^{4 \times 4}$, and $p=3$.

Consider the block decomposition of $K \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ into

$K=\begin{pmatrix} P & Q\\Q^T & R\end{pmatrix}$ and of its inverse $L=K^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} P' & Q'\\Q'^T & R'\end{pmatrix}$, where $P$ and $P'$ are $p \times p$ blocks.

We have in particular the following relationships:

$PP'+QQ'^T=I_p \ \ (1) \ \ \ \ PQ'+QR'=0  \ \ (2) \ \ $ and

$Q^TP'+RQ'^T=0  \ \ (3) \ \ \ \ Q^TQ'+RR' = I_{n-p}  \ \ (4)$

We are interested in the eigenvalues of matrix $L:=PP'$ (dimensions $p \times p$).

Using (1), we have $L=I-QQ'^T \ \ (5)$.

I will take in the following the particular case $n=4$ and $p=n-1=3$. Thus $R, R' \in \mathbb{R}^3$, that we will denote by lowercase letters $r, r'$.

We are in a case where matrix $L$ has an eigenvalue 1 with multiplicity 2 and another eigenvalue $rr'$.

Here is why:

1) By post-multiplication of (5) by $Q$:

$LQ = Q-(QQ'^T)Q = Q-Q(Q'^TQ) = Q-Q(Q'^TQ)$

Using now (4), we have $LQ = rr'Q$ (we use lowercase letters in order to indicate that $r$r et $r'$ are reals), which means that $rr'$ is an eigenvalue associated with eigenvector $Q$. An open question is to show that $rr'>1$.

2) Concerning the two other eigenvalues, let $U$ be any vector of the 2D plane orthogonal to $Q'$, i.e., such that $Q'^TU=0$.

Post-multiplication of (5) by $U$ gives 
$LU = U-(QQ'^T)U = U - Q(Q'^TU) = U$, proving that $U$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue 1.

It means that, in this way, one obtains 2 eigenvectors associated to eigenvalue 1. These eigenvectors are, in general not proportional to $Q$, because $Q$, in general, is not orthogonal to $Q'$.

I wish that, even though the result obtained is partial, it will be of some help to you.

Remark 1: We have not used the fact that the matrices are positive definite.

Remark 2: if, for example, n=13, according to the value of $p$, here is the order of multiplicity $m$ of eigenvalue one that can be observed in the simulations:

$p=7 \ \ \ p=8 \ \ \ p=9 \ \ \ p=10 \ \ \ p=11 \ \ p=12$

$m=1 \ \ m=3 \ \ m=5 \ \ m=7 \ \ m=9 \ \ m=11$

Matlab script:

$\begin{verbatim}
clear all;close all;
n=7;m=n-1;
for k=1:10
    T=orth(rand(n));D=diag(10*rand(1,n));
    K=T*D*T';
    L=inv(K);
    M=K(1:m,1:m)*L(1:m,1:m);
    sort(eig(M))
    Q=K(1:m,(m+1):n);S=L(1:m,(m+1):n);
    1-Q'*S
    M*Q-(1-Q'*S)*Q
    %is the null vector proving that Q is
    %an eigenvector of M associated with the eigenvalue 1-Q'S
end
\end{verbatim}$

Comment: You observation on the multiplicity of eigenvalue 1 is very interesting.

Comment: Actually, the multiplicity is very easily explained. Since $Q'^{T}$ is a  $(n-p)\times p$ matrix, and we have to find a sub vector space in $R^{p}$ such that for any vector v in the subspace, $Q'^{T} v=0$, thus the dimension of the vector space is $p-(n-p)=2p - n$.

Comment: I write a matlab code too and find that the positive definite condition is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

$$K=\begin{pmatrix} A & B\\B^T & C\end{pmatrix}$$
$$K^{-1}=\begin{pmatrix} (A-BC^{-1}B^T)^{-1}&*\\*&*\end{pmatrix}$$

A positive definite implies that:$A=PP,P=P^{T}$

$$A(A-BC^{-1}B^T)^{-1}=(I-BC^{-1}B^{T}P^{-1}P^{-1})^{-1}$$

$(I-BC^{-1}B^{T}P^{-1}P^{-1})$ is similar to $(I-P^{T}BC^{-1}B^{T}P^{-1})$.

Since C is positive definite,the eigenvalues of  $(I-P^{T}BC^{-1}B^{T}P^{-1})$ are less equal than 1.

Since K is positive definite, $(I-P^{T}BC^{-1}B^{T}P^{-1})$ is positive definite.QED.